# Prove that $v$ is the $\alpha$-weak partial derivative of $u$ in $U_1\cup U2$.

Tags: analysis, partial-derivative, weak-derivatives

Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be two open sets in $\Bbb R^n$
for some $n ≥ 1$ such that $U_1 \cap U_2 = ∅$. Let
$\alpha= (\alpha_1, . . . , \alpha_n)$ be a multiindex. Let $u ∈ L^1_{loc}(U1 ∪ U2)$. Assume that the $\alpha$-weak
partial derivatives of $u$ in $U_1$ and $U_2$ exist, and denote them by $v_1$ and $v_2$, respectively.

(1) Prove that $v_1=v_2$ a.e. in $U_1 \cap U_2$.

(2) Define $v$ by $v=v_1$ in $U_1$\ $U_2$, $v =v_2$ in $U_2$\ $U_1$, and $v= v_1$ in $U_1\cap U_2$. Prove
that $v$ is the $\alpha$-weak partial derivative of $u$ in $U_1\cup U2$.

I solved part 1, but can someone tell me how to solve part 2 please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_c(U_1\cup U_2)$ with support $K$. Write $K=K_1\cup K_2$ for $K_1\subseteq U_1$ and $K_2\subseteq U_2$ compact. Pick open sets $K_j\subseteq V_j\subseteq \bar{V_j}\subseteq U_j$ and let $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ be a partition of unity subordinate to this cover (i.e., let $V_3$ be open such that $V_1\cup V_2\cup V_3=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $V_3\cap K_1=V_3\cap K_2=\emptyset$ and let $\psi_1,\psi_2,\psi_3$ be a partition of unity subordinate to that cover).

Then, we have

\begin{align}
\int_{U_1\cup U_2} v\varphi=\int_{V_1} v\psi_1\varphi+\int_{V_2} v\psi_2\varphi&=(-1)^{|\alpha|} \left(\int_{V_1} u\partial^{\alpha}(\psi_1 \varphi)+\int_{V_2} u\partial^{\alpha}(\psi_2 \varphi)\right)\\
&=(-1)^{|\alpha|}\int_{U_1\cup U_2} u\partial^{\alpha}((\psi_1+\psi_2)\varphi)
\\&=(-1)^{|\alpha|}\int_{U_1\cup U_2} u\partial^{\alpha}\varphi,
\end{align}

where, of course, we've used that $v$ is the weak derivative of $u$ in both $U_1$ and in $U_2$.